# Hopf fibration homeomorphism injectivity

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, hopf-fibration

I was wondering if there is a possibility to proof the homeomorphism between the 1-dimensional complex projective space  $\mathbb{C}P^1$ and the 2-sphere $S^2$ via the Hopf fibration (I know already that there is an explicit homeomorphism between these two spaces). 
Here is my idea: let $\pi:S^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{C}P^1$ be the natural projection to the quotient and let $H:S^3 \rightarrow S^2$. It is easy to see that these two maps pass to the quotient, then because of the universal property of the quotient topology there is an unique continuous map $f:\mathbb{C}P^1 \rightarrow S^2$ such that  $f \circ \pi=H$. f is surjective because $\pi$ and $H$ are surjective maps and $f$ is also closed because is a map which satisfies the hypothesis of the closed map lemma. The problem I have is to show that $f$ is injective and I think it is not trivial to show. Could somebody help me please?

Comment: On a note that doesn't answer your question, you'll find that your continuous map $f$ *is* the standard identification between $\Bbb{CP}^1$ and $S^2$ you know exists but don't want to use.

Comment: Thank you, yes exactly I know there is an explicit homeomorphism, I was just wondering if without that one could deduct the injectivity of f

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is your definition of $H$?

Comment: @TedShifrin H(z,w):=(2zw*,|z|^2 - |w|^2)

Comment: So, this is just the map to $\Bbb CP^1$ followed by the inverse of stereographic projection to the sphere.

Comment: @TedShifrin which should be the explicit homeomorphism that I mentioned in the above question?